New Message Event trigger or processing is taking several minutes
I want to use  telethon to send me messages, if the content of a message contains a keyword and if this message was sent in a specific channel (like deal-channels). Since I cannot add any bot to the channels I'm interested in, I then send any relevant message to a channel with just me and a bot, to get a notification from the bot; that's working fine.
My problem is my code seems to wait until a specific time and then send all the messages at once, resulting in minutes-long delays for forwarding some messages.
As far as I understand, there may be a reason the code gets stuck for approximately 15 minutes (not at the start, somehow), and then "resets" or something, and then works through all "new" messages.
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from time import gmtime, strftime
from datetime import datetime

api_id = 123123123 
api_hash = 'e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e00e0e'


client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()


@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    #getting id from chat
    income_id=str(event.chat_id)
    #logging time
    minutes=int(datetime.today().minute- event.date.minute)
    seconds=int(datetime.today().second- event.date.second)
    if minutes <0:
        minutes=60+minutes
    if seconds <0:
        minutes=minutes-1
        seconds=seconds+60
    #only log, if from relevant channels
    if income_id == "-channel1" or income_id == "-channel2" or income_id == "-channel3" :
        
     
        print( "minutes: " +str(minutes)  + " seconds:" + str(seconds) + '; ' + event.text[:2])
        await client.send_message(>my own channel<,'recieved:' + event.date.strftime(("%H:%M:%S")) + ' send in Telegram: '+ strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()) + '; Inhalt: ' + event.text[:2])
        
        

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()


recieved:09:00:09 send in Telegram: 09:00:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:12
recieved:09:00:15 send in Telegram: 09:00:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:5
recieved:09:03:19 send in Telegram: 09:03:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:2
recieved:09:02:28 send in Telegram: 09:03:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:53
recieved:09:12:16 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 2:5
recieved:09:05:17 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 9:4
recieved:09:09:38 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 4:43
recieved:09:08:33 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 5:48
recieved:09:09:25 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 4:56
recieved:09:10:25 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 3:56
recieved:09:04:20 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 10:1
recieved:09:09:31 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 4:50
recieved:09:09:29 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 4:52
recieved:09:11:14 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 3:7
recieved:09:11:26 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 2:55
recieved:09:13:14 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 1:7
recieved:09:13:57 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:24
recieved:09:12:12 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 2:9
recieved:09:04:09 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 10:12
recieved:09:13:05 send in Telegram: 09:14:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 1:16
recieved:09:15:33 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 13:48
recieved:09:18:47 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 10:34
recieved:09:18:47 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 10:34
recieved:09:15:33 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 13:48
recieved:09:19:14 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 10:7
recieved:09:16:17 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 13:4
recieved:09:21:23 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 7:58
recieved:09:28:22 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:59
recieved:09:20:27 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 8:54
recieved:09:28:26 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:55
recieved:09:24:32 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 4:49
recieved:09:27:28 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 1:53
recieved:09:29:13 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:8
recieved:09:15:29 send in Telegram: 09:29:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 13:52
recieved:09:29:23 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 14:58
recieved:09:30:11 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 14:10
recieved:09:41:02 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 3:19
recieved:09:31:17 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 13:4
recieved:09:34:27 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 9:54
recieved:09:39:15 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 5:6
recieved:09:44:16 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:5
recieved:09:41:18 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 3:3
recieved:09:38:25 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 5:56
recieved:09:42:17 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 2:4
recieved:09:35:15 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 9:6
recieved:09:44:16 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:5
recieved:09:41:19 send in Telegram: 09:44:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 3:2
recieved:09:56:30 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 2:51
recieved:09:58:27 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:54
recieved:09:55:13 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 4:8
recieved:09:57:21 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 2:0
recieved:09:45:35 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 13:46
recieved:09:45:20 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 14:1
recieved:09:46:24 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 12:57
recieved:09:46:26 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 12:55
recieved:09:47:23 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 11:58
recieved:09:59:20 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:1
recieved:09:58:31 send in Telegram: 09:59:21 ;delayed by (m:s) 0:50

I tried to shrink down the code to the minimum, and started logging times. Tried to run in cmd and idle shell.
